# Icon resources missing after deploying by Clickonce method

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an outlook add-in, i have a form with a button which has a "Close.png" icon the Imagesource of the button is

```
<Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Close.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
```

, when i deploy the solution using clickonce and after install it successfully and when i tried to run it from outlook y got the following exception message: "\Addin.Outlook\Addin.Outlook\publish\Resources\Close.png", having Content as build action and copy always as copy to output directory.
I need some help, cheers.

Comment: Set the build action of the icon as Resource.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work, could you please tell me with details how can i do it.

Comment: Righ Click on the Icon -> Properties -> Build Action -> Resource

Comment: it does not work also after changing build action to resource.

Comment: Are you referring this Icon from other DLL?

Comment: No it is in the same dll

Comment: In your project properties go to `Publish` and then `Application Files`.  These are all the files ClickOnce will deploy.  You should look for the image you're talking about and that it's set to `Include`.

Comment: If you are making the build action to resource then you should use <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Close.png"/>

Comment: You can set you Build action to Copy to Output and use the Siteoforigin in PackURI as <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Close.png"/>

Comment: Refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are making the build action to resource then you should use

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Close.png"/>
```

You can set Build action to Copy to Output and use the Siteoforigin in PackURI as

`<ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Close.png"/>`

Refer the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

two steps

1. build action: content and allways copy(Righ Click on the Icon -> Properties -> Build Action ..)
2. must be the same folder as .csproj